# Move hash bang at the end of URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, hash

Working on a project and one of the requirements is to make it work on IE9. I am using angular js to route. Everything is working perfectly but in IE9 where my link is like:

```
www.mysite.co.uk/#!/news
```

This means my site is never routed to /news from what i read all the routing ends as soon the url hits the hash bang.

How can I move the hash bang to the end of the url like so:

```
www.mysite.co.uk/news/#!/
```

Comment: why to the end of the url ?

Comment: well them I can access the page under www.mysite.co.uk/news. orget rid of this hash bang all together

Comment: you use angulars html5mode to get rid of the hashbang https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: You state one of your requirements is to support IE9, therefore you must use hashbang mode (ie, you can't get rid of it). I suggest you check out the [angular reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for details.